# How to get the address of an already deployed contract in hardhat's network?

Tags: blockchain, ether, ethereumjs, hardhat

I'm working with hardhat's local network, and I want to get the address of a deployed contract. I want to avoid deploying the contract again just to get the new address; I want to get the existing contract address, and then interact with it (so basically I have one script to deploy it, another one to interact with it).

In Truffle, the artifacts contain this contract address field, but not in hardhat. I reviewed the transactions manually (using `eth_getTransactionByHash` and `eth_getBlockByNumber`) but I get all the information needed **except** the contract address.

Shouldn't it be possible to get it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you could get it afterwards.

What I do in my depoyment script is that I save the address to a JSON file for frontend to use. My (a bit cleaned up) is like this:

```
async function saveFrontendFiles(tokenAddr: string) {
  const contractsDir = __dirname + "/../website/src/contracts";

  if (!fs.existsSync(contractsDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(contractsDir);
  }

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + "/contract-address.json",
    JSON.stringify(
      {
        Token: tokenAddr
      },
      undefined,
      2
    )
  );

  const TokenArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync("MyTokenMock");

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + "/Token.json",
    JSON.stringify(TokenArtifact, null, 2)
  );
}
```

Comment: I see, that could work in my set up, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. It is now possible out of the box. (as far as I know)

While writing a custom solution where I would store the addresses of the deployed contract in a .json file (like in Truffle), I discovered that there is a plugin called `hardhat-deploy` that is able to do this.

Comment: hey, this plugin you mean?
https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy

Comment: @bakeiro yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this answers your question, but I was looking back a project I had deployed a while back and figuring out the contract address for it. When I deployed it at the time using hardhat, you have to write the abi and contract into a .json file. This will be something you code into your deployment script. Something like:

```
await xxxx.deployed();

//Pull the address and ABI out while you deploy, since that will be key in interacting with the smart contract later
const data = {
    address: xxxx.address,
    abi: JSON.parse(xxxx.interface.format("json")),
  };

fs.writeFileSync("./src/xxxx.json", JSON.stringify(data));
```

So for an existing project, look for what json you produced through your deployment script. The first key for the json file will be the contract address.